# Reason why the name Ben Tziyon is a Segula for a long life

Tags: names, segulah

I saw in [Igros Kodesh 11, page 73](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15895&st=&pgnum=90) mentioned in the Chida in the name of the Yerushalmi that the name Ben Tziyon is a Segula for a long life and good years. What is the reason that this name has such a strength?

Comment: It looks like the Chida's statement is in Shem Hagedolim volume one, in the Kuntres Acharon on Ma'arechet Bet. It appears that Hebrew Books does not have a version with the Kuntres Acharon, although I could just be looking in the wrong places. Here's a link to one of the Sefarim on Hebrewbooks.org (there are several): http://hebrewbooks.org/30594

Comment: Thanks to the wikipedia article http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D, I found a much better version here: http://daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=306 . It does have the Kuntres Acharon, but it doesn't give much more information (page 6 of this pdf: http://daat.ac.il/daat/vl/shemhagdolim/shemhagdolim05.pdf )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The segula that the name "Ben Tzion" is associated with long life is also brought by [R' Rachamim Nissim Yitzchok Palagi](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%92%27%D7%99) in Yafeh La-Lev ([Chelek Gimmel Y.D. Siman 265 Ois 7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7660&st=&pgnum=179)). He connects it with two Pesukim in Tehillim:

> שיר המעלות הבטחים בה' כהר ציון לא ימוט לעולם ישב - A song of ascents. Those who trust in the Lord are like Mount Zion, which will not falter but will abide forever. ([125:1](http://beta.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16346/jewish/Chapter-125.htm))
>
> כטל חרמון שירד על הררי ציון כי שם צוה ה' את הברכה חיים עד העולם - As the dew of Hermon which runs down on the mountains of Zion, for there the Lord commanded the blessing, life forever. [(133:3)](http://beta.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16354)